# css background-position conflicts with outer div's background-color

Tags: html, css

Css background-position conflicts with outer div's background-color

i.e.:

```
 background-color: yellow;
 background-position: xxxxx;
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wodecaoxin/Lo1L0vyw/)

Symptom: **line 2 comment will affect the button animation.**

Please Uncomment line 2 to see the conflict.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question? The buttons look fine in the JSFiddle?

Comment: yeah whats wrong? those are some nice buttons in that fiddle

Comment: It looks ok in chrome. which OS/browser do you use?

Comment: ah i see now, how about putting an extra div around your buttons with a white background or something?

Comment: What makes you think background-position has any effect on background-color?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changes done.

**CSS**

```
#content {
     background-color: yellow;
     position: relative;       /* make position relative  */
     z-index: 0;               /* reduce the z-index */
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adarshkr/Lo1L0vyw/6/)**